# Git clone doesn't work remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

I'm trying to clone my private repo from the remote host and it works on every other computer but doesn't work for me for some reason.

I have already tried,

```
git remote rm origin
```

and

```
git remote add origin {{url for git repo}}
```

but no luck. Is there a way to completely reset the Git configurations on my local computer?

Comment: Please tell us what you're actually trying to do. Your question doesn't make sense, cloning and remotes have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

`git clone` has nothing to do with `git remote`. Remotes are only involved **after** you have already successfully cloned a repo.

If you're trying to clone a repo, you need `git clone <url for git repo>`. If that isn't working, stop playing with `git remote`, because that has *nothing* to do with cloning repositories.

There is no configuration setting you can change here, you simply need to figure out what the real URL for your repository is and run `git clone <url>`.

Comment: actually thats what i did in the first place. then lots of online tutorials directed me to remove the origin which i did. but still i get repository not found error when i try to clone it.

Comment: You misunderstood those tutorials. You cannot even **do** `git remote <anything>` until *after* you've successfully cloned a repo. `git remote` is for managing the remotes of a cloned repository. Until you're actually inside a clone repository, you have no use for `git remote`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via command line via `git remote rm origin`. But here's an alternative:

In the .git folder inside your repository you will find a file called **config**, which will contain something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/Acme/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Just erase this section and after this just run: `git remote add <your_url>`